# Using library build with .NET Stanard Library in a .NET 4.6 project

Tags: .net, .net-standard, .net-4.6

There are some projects:

- Library LibA targeting .NET Standard Library
- Application Proj46 targeting .NET Framework 4.6
- Applicatoin ProjC targeting .NET Core 1.0

LibA does something:

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static void Bar()
    {
        using (var f = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((a) => { }));
    }
}
```

Thus it requires the dependencies

- NETStandard.Library
- System.Threading.ThreadPool
- System.Threading.Thread

LibA project.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "System.Threading.ThreadPool": "4.0.10",
    "System.Threading.Thread": "4.0.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.3": { }
  }
}
```

Proj46 uses LibA:

```
LibA.Foo.Bar();
```

There's an FileNotFoundException at runtime saying: 'File or assembly "System.IO.FileSystem, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" not found'. In order to work, I have to add all the dependencies to Proj46.

Is it possible to build LibA using .NET Standard Library, without having to install all it's dependencies to any upstream project?
AFAIK .NET46 implements .NETStandard1.3. Thus it should not be required to have it as a dependency.

EDIT:

[Complete solution to reproduce](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fdbipcgwynu9mjf/Example.zip?dl=0)

The exception goes away, after adding nuget packages "NETStandard.Library", "System.Threading.Thread" and "System.Threading.ThreadPool" to Proj46.

Comment: It would help if you'd provide a [mcve]. You've shown us *some* parts (one of the project.json files but not the other) and *some* of the error message, but not everything.Two C# files and two project.json files - so we can reproduce this - would make things much easier. (I don't think ProjC is relevant here, as far as I can see...) Are you sure you're specifying ".NETStandard1.3" rather than "netstandard1.3" btw? That's not a framework name I know...

Comment: I mentioned ProjC just for completeness, to justify targeting .NET standard. (I'll provide an example.)

Comment: The current tooling is broken. Wait for its RTM build.

Comment: @LexLi Good point! Is the tooling for .NET Standard included in the ".NET Core 1.0.0 SDK"? Is there an issue on github? (It's NOT [3926](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3926) )

Comment: .NET Core is 1.0 RTM, but its SDK as well as other tooling are all Preview 2. Consider that as a big roadblock and everyone should be caution. I personally suggest waiting for tooling RTM instead locating all kinds of workarounds around the internet.